# How to parse this NOAA Weather Alert CAP in PHP?

Tags: php, weather

Greetings,

I am having some difficulty understanding how to parse NOAA's Weather Alert CAP in PHP. I need to do the following:

- Locate the proper county in the feed
- Verify that there is an active alert
- Display the alert's description

The feed I am working with is at this address - http://www.weather.gov/alerts/va.cap
I have used `simplexml_load_string()` in the past for this sort of thing but it does not seem to work for this feed.

Thanks!

Comment: "does not seem to work"? Please explain. What is returned by `simplexml_load_string`?

Comment: Sorry about that. It returns an empty array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more time on Google I came across a script that does exactly what I am trying to do. Rather than try to reinvent the wheel, I am going to go with it. http://saratoga-weather.org/scripts-atom.php#atomadvisory

Answer (score 1):

You are probably having an issue due to the namespace

```
<cap:alert xmlns:cap='http://www.incident.com/cap/1.0'>
```

This should give you an idea of how to extract information

```
$sxe = simplexml_load_file('http://www.weather.gov/alerts/va.cap');
foreach ($sxe->getDocNamespaces() as $ns => $uri) {
    $sxe->registerXPathNamespace($ns, $uri);
}
foreach($sxe->xpath('//cap:areaDesc') as $areaDesc) {
    echo $areaDesc;
}
```

On a sidenote, SimpleXml is for simple XML only. Consider using DOM instead.

Comment: Okay, this looks like a step in the right direction. Your code outputs all of the areas and gives me an idea of the structure. But how to drill down to just one county, determine if there is an active alert, and output the details?

Comment: @Night The counties are those in the description? Sorry, I'm not american. And what makes an active alert?

Comment: //cap:areaDesc outputs the name of a county, I am trying to narrow down the entire list of counties to one and retrieve the information for that particular county. For example, just the details for Wise (VA).

Comment: @Night How do you know there is an "active alert". What in the document tells you that?

Comment: See my answer. Rather than spend a ton of time trying to figure this out I decided to go with an existing script that does the job quite nicely

Comment: @Night well, that's probably the best and easiest solution. However, I'd appreciate if you'd do that kind of research **before** you ask questions then. It's somewhat annoying to invest *my* time trying to help solve *your* problem and then be left with a comment telling me my effort is put to waste. I dont expect you to accept my answer, but an upvote or at least a Thank you would have been nice.

Comment: I'm sorry, I found the solution right as I was finishing up last night and I had been researching for quite some time prior to coming here. I finally found it in a message board thread, rather by chance. I do appreciate your assistance and you actually pointed me in the right direction when it comes to dealing with this sort of feed. I would have continued down that path but had a time constraint, I might still in the future. So, thank you for your help. :)

Comment: +1 on your comment as well for calling me out, just kind of hit the wall at the tail end of programming yesterday. The client wanted weather details up pronto and the system I had programmed myself was fetching from another state for some reason.

Comment: @Night no problem and no hard feelings. Thanks for understanding!